# PIN in Windows 10: how safe?

Tags: windows-10, pin

Windows 10 enables users to sign in to their device using a PIN (so called **Passport PIN**). Normally is PIN a simple four-digit code and I wonder how can it be safe?

Comment: Using a pin is entirely optional.  There are better ways to identify yourself to your computer, i.e. Windows Hello, then to use a pin.  Worth pointing out 1607 will allow more then 4-digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally is PIN a simple four-digit code ...

A good question, I thought the same but it is wrong!

Please take a look at [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/why-a-pin-is-better-than-a-password?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> PIN can be complex
>
> The Passport PIN is subject to the same set of IT management policies
>   as a password, such as complexity, length, expiration, and history.
>   Although we generally think of a PIN as a simple four-digit code,
>   administrators can set policies for managed devices to require a PIN
>   complexity similar to a password. You can require or block: special
>   characters, uppercase characters, lowercase characters, and digits.
>
> ...
>
> Something like **t758A!** could be an account password or a complex
>   Passport PIN.

Another important points:

> PIN is tied to the device
>
> One important difference between a password and a Passport PIN is that
>   the PIN is tied to the specific device on which it was set up.
>
> PIN is local to the device
>
> PIN is backed by hardware

Comment: You can also revoke your pin/device access by accessing your Microsoft Account.  This would require what ideally would be your password and your 2-factor authentication to accomplish.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you mean a two-step verification?

Comment: I mean 2-factor authentication.  Authenticator + Password = 2-factor authentication.